# How to connect to PSFTP using different username

Tags: amazon-web-services, sftp, putty, centos7

I'm trying to log into PSFTP (Putty SFTP) and I'm able to login only using default username 'centos'. How do I login with different username? 

 
 C:\SMS\Putty>psftp sample (sample is the saved session in my putty which contains hostname and private key) 
login as: centos 
Remote working directory is /home/centos 
psftp> 
 
  Connection is successful. 
 
 Now with different username(other than default i.e., centos) I'm getting below error. 
 
C:\SMS\Putty>psftp sample 
 (sample is the saved session in my putty which contains hostname and private key) 
 
**Error:** 
 
Using username "ashuthi". 
Server refused our key 
Fatal: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent:
 publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the two users have different private keys - are you sure ashuthi's private key is being used (and is correct)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) I got it now.. I did a mistake by not copying public key into ashuthi's .ssh/authorized_keys folder. Once I copied, I was able to login using ashuthi as my username.